# Ran the Add-SPOOrgAssetsLibrary command to add Org Assets but doesn't show up

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, administration, asset-library

I ran the `Add-SPOOrgAssetsLibrary` command to add Org Assets but it doesn't show up.

Using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/add-spoorgassetslibrary?view=sharepoint-ps)

The command I ran below (The CDN was default if i didn't add it in the command):

```
Add-SPOOrgAssetsLibrary -LibraryURL https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/News/Assets -ThumbnailURL https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/New/Assets/Logo.png -OrgAssetType ImageDocumentLibrary
```

When I go to the image using and image web part or any other modern page the org asset tab doesn't show up.

I have ran the command : **Get-SPOOrgAssetsLibrary** and it returns the library I set

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: How much time you waited after adding org assets library? It may take some time to show up in the SharePoint web parts. Check: [Create an Organization Assets Library in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2024/01/30/create-an-organization-assets-library-in-sharepoint-online/).

Comment: It has been over 2 weeks.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may take up to 24 hours for the organization assets library to appear in the SharePoint web parts (in case of image document library) and in the desktop apps (in case of office templates library).

So, you have to wait for some time after registering the new document library as an organization assets library in your SharePoint Online tenant.

**References**:

1. [Create an Organization Assets Library in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2024/01/30/create-an-organization-assets-library-in-sharepoint-online/)
2. [Register SharePoint Document Library as an Organization Assets Library using PowerShell](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2024/02/03/register-sharepoint-document-library-as-an-organization-assets-library-using-powershell/)
3. [Create an organization assets library](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/organization-assets-library?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

Comment: It has been over 2 weeks. Thanks